# Change BGP AS number after configuration

Tags: router, bgp, cisco-ios

I am trying to implement and test BGP in a lab environment. Due to some error, I have assigned wrong AS numbers to the routers and I would like to change that. Simply running the same commands with the correct configuration does not work. I have also tried to reset the BGP connection. But that resets the peers and not the router settings. Is there a way to simply remove any ad all BGP configurations that are present on teh router and such that the router will then have no instabnce of BGP running and I can start afresh with the configurations?

Comment: This is a implementation specific question, so without telling us on which equipment and routing software you're trying to do this we can't help.

Comment: @TeunVink cisco IoS , router cisco - IoSv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (but removes all bgp config):

```
no router bgp [old ASN]
router bgp [new ASN]
(rest of new config)
```